# Single Touch Read as Scroll Action

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, touch

I have a WPF application which is designed to be used on a touch screen.

I use a list view with a set of images, with the selected image appearing in a full size image control

When on touch screen I can select the images simply by touching the image on the list view item however I have a small issue.

When the user touches the screen, often the users finger moves slightly whilst still in contact with the screen, leading to the list view interpreting the touch as a scroll request.

This means that the desired selection only actually happens when the user is careful or happens to have no movement whilst in contact with the screen.

I assume that this is an issue with the threshold at which it determines a scroll action is requested, but I cant find any solution to this problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually toggle the [PanningMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the ListView's [internal Scrollviewer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/794815aa-9a1e-4b57-b097-71d8672f331b/getting-the-scrollviewer-from-listview?forum=wpf). Here is how to get the scrollviewer :

```
// Get the border of the listview (first child of a listview)
Decorator border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myListView, 0) as Decorator;

// Get scrollviewer
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
```

Now you can access the scrollviewer `PanningMode` property.

You would only set the panningmode to `VerticalFirst` once the finger has moved a specific threshold of your taste using the [ManipulationDelta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event, and you set it to `None` again when the finger is released ([ManipulationCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted(v=vs.100).aspx) event raised).